# Media RSS and Zend

Tags: zend-framework, magento, cooliris, mediarss

I have a Magento application running atop Zend framework. I like to generate Media RSS feed in Zend (In orded to feed the Cooliris application).

**Does anyone know if Zend framework supports Media RSS feed?**

(I didn't find anything in http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.feed.html, but maybe I dint look in the right place?)

Tx,

Sty

Answer (score -1):

Check the comments on the page you referred to for [`Zend_Feed_Writer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html#zend.feed.writer.getting.started) and the entry in the API for syntax.

Comment: There is precisely one comment, and it's asking the same question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: It's just that my answer is three + years old and that comment is one year old..

Comment: And archive.org doesn't show the comments from three years ago because they're loaded by JavaScript. This is a perfect example of why answers should summarise the main point of linked resources.

Comment: +1, SO is highly temporary in any case since no one ever would've gone back here to edit for, say, API breaking changes in code examples used.